# How to use same line of Code again and again in multiple view controller in ios

Tags: ios

I am working on a MultiView application in which have a home Screen(Is Not the RootView Controller in the application). In order to pop to that Home screen I am using the following:

```
for (UIViewController *controller in [self.navigationController viewControllers]) {
    if ([controller isKindOfClass:[B class]]) {
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller animated:YES];
        break;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to write the above line using a Macro or something like that?
 Might be this seems funny to you folks, but I am curious to know.

Comment: put it in the AppDelegate with a method convention, N call wherever you want .

Comment: similar way, Use the subClass of NSObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it in .pch file

```
`#define callThisMtd(B) for (UIViewController *controller in [self.navigationController viewControllers]){if ([controller isKindOfClass:[B class]]){ [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller animated:YES]; break;}}`
```

ad call it from any viewcontroller

```
callThisMtd(objB); //where objB is your B object
```

Comment: I am looking for the same.But have a query as i am not able to call like this ***callThisMtd()*** but working fine with the parameter ***callThisMtd(VC);*** (the view controller that i want to pop at).

Comment: Even I've given the parameter, callThisMtd(objB); objB is the paarmeter

Answer (score 4):

You can use category method.

Just write one line whenever you want to use

```
[self.navigationController goToHome];
```

// interface

```
  @interface  UINavigationController(CustomMethod)
-(void)goToHome;
@end
```

// implementation

```
@implementation UINavigationController(CustomMethod)

-(void)goToHome{
    for (UIViewController *controller in [self.navigationController viewControllers]){
        if ([controller isKindOfClass:[B class]]){
            [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller animated:YES];
            break;}
    }
}

@end
```